# How can I run one method of a class automatically, before any other class methods in Python, when a new class instance is created

Tags: python, class

Question says it all: I have a class in python which has several methods, and I want one of them to be run before any of the other functions in the class.
I want to store the result of this calculation in a variable called cache, so I can save the data and minimize function calling for optimization purposes. What is the best way to accomplish this? Example code is listed below:

```py
class Foo: 
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        self.cache = []

    def baz(self):
        #do some calculation
        #store it in the cache
        self.cache.append(<result of calculation>)
        return 0
    
    def qux(self):
        # this function requires the output of baz in the cache
        # How can I automatically have this class run the baz method before any other method of the class so that I can utilize the cache?
        return 0
```

As always, if you take the time to answer or attempt to answer this question, thank you for your time.

Comment: You can call it in init. Normally though, I'd call it when needed, perhaps with a get_baz() method. There's no need to compute it if it never gets used on that instance.

Comment: There are slight differences in how you would handle this, depending on how many values can be stored in the cache. Is it either empty or containing one value? Or are there different values that any given call to `baz` could produce, based on the current state of the object. Note that this is very closely related to memoization, where `qux` would simply call `baz` unconditionally, and `baz` would check its argument to see if it's already been called with that argument and retrieve a cached value to return instead of re-computing the return value.

Comment: That is, `qux` should not worry about whether a value is in the cache already; it should just call `baz`, and let `baz` populate the cache if it hasn't been already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If baz is always going to be needed in every circumstance, put it in `__init__`.

If baz is always going to be needed for `qux`, put a call to `baz` in `qux` with a test.

In `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, bar):
    self.bar = bar
    self.cache = []
    self.baz()
```

In `baz`:

```
def qux(self):
    try:
        self.calculation(self.cache)
    except:
        self.baz()
        self.calculation(self.cache)
```

where your calculations are being carried out in `calculation(self, cache_set)` which should raise an exception if no cache is present.